# Multiple questions on BIRT

Tags: numbers, birt, page-break

I am new to BIRT.

1. I have a requirement to print a HEADING based on a database value. How do I do that?
2. How do I leave a Blank line upon break in one of the fields I am reporting?
3. In the footer, I need to say "Page X of Y" where Y is the total number of pages?

Answer (score 3):

1. After creating the data source, switch to the "Master Page" and drag the field in question into the header.
2. No idea.
3. There are a couple of computed fields (called "AutoText") available. One of them renders itself as the total number of pages.

Answer (score -3):

As you are new to BIRT it would be good to start with the [Tutorials](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/tutorial/). Reading the [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ)s is usually enlightening, too. Make sure to check out the [BIRT community resources](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/community.php) like the mailing list archives, etc. too.